# How to Include generated App Manifest in MSIX file in Windows Application Packaging Project

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms, msix

I am writing a VB.NET Windows Forms application that needs to be deployed with a package identity so I am generating MSIX files for it. I would like the application to be high-DPI enabled, so I set the needed key in app.manifest. When building the application and running it without the MSIX packaging, the high-DPI support works fine. When building and running the MSIX packaging through a Windows Application Packaging Project, high-DPI support does not work. (I have previously tried specifying high DPI support in app.config, but apparently that disables visual styles for VB.NET applications, and I would rather not disable application framework to try and fix the issue.)

It appears that the generated app manifest file is not included in the MSIX file. How can I include this file.

Contents of my debug build directory without MSIX packaging:

```
10/14/2020  05:27 PM    <DIR>          .
10/14/2020  05:27 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/14/2020  05:27 PM    <DIR>          app.publish
03/19/2019  12:46 AM           160,160 System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
03/19/2019  12:46 AM            72,096 System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll
10/22/2018  08:48 PM            24,064 Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd
10/22/2018  08:48 PM         5,612,032 Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd
08/09/2018  05:44 PM           174,080 windows.winmd
10/14/2020  05:27 PM             1,899 MyApp.application
10/14/2020  05:21 PM            24,064 MyApp.exe
10/13/2020  03:31 PM               369 MyApp.exe.config
10/14/2020  05:27 PM             6,371 MyApp.exe.manifest
10/14/2020  05:21 PM            54,784 MyApp.pdb
10/14/2020  05:21 PM               727 MyApp.xml
              11 File(s)      6,130,646 bytes
               3 Dir(s)   7,844,708,352 bytes free
```

Contents of my debug build directory with MSIX packaging:

```
10/14/2020  05:16 PM    <DIR>          .
10/14/2020  05:16 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/19/2019  12:46 AM           160,160 System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
03/19/2019  12:46 AM            72,096 System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll
10/14/2020  05:16 PM            24,064 MyApp.exe
10/13/2020  03:31 PM               369 MyApp.exe.config
10/14/2020  05:16 PM            54,784 MyApp.pdb
               5 File(s)        311,473 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   7,842,045,952 bytes free
```

`MyApp.exe.manifest` does not seem to be included in the MSIX package, and I would like to include it. How would I do so in a Windows Application Packaging Project?

Visual Studio 2019 Community 16.7.6, .NET Framework 4.8, Windows 10 version 1909.

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that adding DpiAwareness support in app.config *disables visual styles for VB.NET applications*? Setting the DpiAwareness in app.config is also  recommended when targeting 4.7.2+. Btw, why aren't you packaging the app in Release?

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for your reply! I’m still developing so I’m packaging as debug for now. The visual styles bug I pointed out is mentioned here: https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-early-access/issues/39#issuecomment-427841391. I’d rather set high DPI support in app.config but it seems that I’d need to implement more complicated code to reenable visual styles.

Comment: Visual Styles (in early access 4.8) are not disabled, this setting is (was) configured too late for the `PerMonitorV2` DpiAwaress to work correctly (in combination with other settings). Note that, if you set the DpiAwaress in app.manifest, you override what's been set in app.config. -- Check whether you have two app.manifest files in your application. It looks like you have added one *manually*. The default one is inside the `My Project` folder.

Comment: I’ll look into that, thanks!

Comment: @Jimi I commented out the app manifest entry and enabled the app.config entry. I also set the target back to .NET Framework 4.7.2. When I launched the app, it supported high-DPI but visual styles were disabled.

Comment: Setting the dpi-awareness value in app.config doesn't disable the ApplicationFramework, which is what calls `Application.EnableVisualStyles()`, in `Application.Designer.vb` (and, btw, you can also enable VisualStyles in the constructor - `public Sub New()` - of the app's starting Form, before calling `InitializeComponent()`) -- I have no idea what you set or changed. -- In your Project Explorer, set the option to visualize all files, so you can access `My Project -> app.manifest` directly. Open it up, verify it's the good one and uncomment the entire `<dependency>` section.

Comment: Also, in app.manifest, in the `<compatibility><application>` branch you have to enable all the System supported: you **have** to enable Windows 10 there.